# How would I include a (VFP) merge module in an ASP.NET Web Deployment Project?

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment-project, visual-foxpro, merge-module

I have an ASP.NET application that is installed using a Web Deployment Project. I'd like to add the Visual FoxPro merge module to the installer. Does anyone have examples of how to do this - or how to install *any* merge module in a Web Deployment Project?

Going to WiX will be my fallback, but as the Web Deployment Project is working effectively, I'd rather stick with it, if I can.

The application is developed using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do with the merge modules, but if you need VFP capabilities, you SHOULD be able to get away with just including the following 4 files in whatever path needs access...

VFP9.exe
VFP9R.dll
VFP9RENU.dll
VFP9T.dll

above are obviously VFP9, but would respectively be for version 8 and 7 too.  You can take a VFP app, or anything relying on VFP, put in a stand-alone directory with these files and run it (provided you have your other tables as needed).

These files should be found within your Windows\System32 folder if a VFP application has been so installed.

Also, if you are doing web, and going through OleDb, you'll have to get that driver from M$ too.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Visual FoxPro Required Runtime Files are: vfp9r.dll, vfp9t.dll, vfp9renu.dll, msvcr71.dll, and gdiplus.dll

As DRapp mentioned, you can simply include these files in the same folder with the compiled application.

Additional files may be required, depending on the features included in the application. A detailed list can be found here [VFP 9 Runtime Files](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFP9RuntimeFiles~VFP)